# Wait for a script to finish

Tags: powershell

I am using a script which backups the folders and than in the next block tries to delete those folder from there original location.This is the script

```
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
  # 3. BACKUP script
  ./bakup_mysite.ps1

  # 4. DELETE CONTENTS OF my_site
  get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\" -recurse | % {
    remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
  }
}
```

If I put a `Read-Host` after step 3 it does stop and ask the user to press any key and then it deletes the next block. But I want to put a wait so the user doesn't have to press any key and everything happens automatically.

This is the backup code which gets called from my_site.ps1

```
$Service_folder_name = 'C:\Services\'
$Pics_folder_name = 'C:\Pics\'


$Date = Get-Date

$folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")

$backup_folder_name = 'c:\_Backups\my_site\' + $folder_date

if (!(Test-Path -path $backup_folder_name)) {

New-Item $backup_folder_name -type directory
}

if ((Test-Path -path $Pics_folder_name)) {
gi $pics_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1 $backup_folder_name\pics.zip $_
}

if ((Test-Path -path $Service_folder_name)) {
gi $Service_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1 $backup_folder_name\Services.zip $_
}
```

Comment: I would like the backup to finish first and than delete the original files, because if i use the above script while backup up some files gets locked and at the same time the next block gets executed and it tries to delete the files thats why i would like to put a wait for backup to finish

Comment: Tried using -wait on the backup script?

Comment: I tried using it but no luck, may be i am not using the write syntax will it be possible if you can make some changes in my script

Comment: Normally `bakup_mysite.ps1` should run synchronously, i.e. return only after it completed its run. If the script returns before the operation is finished then something launched by it is running in the background. We need to see what that is to be able to advise.

Comment: Yea what Ansgar said, the problem isn't here it is in your `bakup_mysite.ps1`

Comment: @user ok I lied it's not in your bakup_mysite.ps1, but we are closer. The problem is in your `out_zip.ps1` where you are calling `.CopyHere()`. Invoking a shell com object and calling copyHere does not wait for the script to finish. Compression is started by the script, the script closes, but the process is still running. See here :http://superuser.com/questions/290461/powershell-zip-file-synchronously

Answer (score 2):

For Powershell cmdlets or functions, PowerShell waits before starting the next command. If it is not the case for your backup script, the trick is to pipeline to Out-Null :

```
./bakup_mysite.ps1 | Out-Null
```

PowerShell will wait until your script has exited before continuing.

Another option is to use a background job:

```
$BackupJob = Start-Job -FilePath "\Path\To\bakup_mysite.ps1"
Wait-Job $BackupJob
```

Powershell will wait until the job $BackupJob has completed before moving on to the next commands.

Comment: i am using this now, it didnt give me any error on deletion but this time it didnt back up anything   $BackupJob = Start-Job { ./bakup_mysite.ps1 }
Wait-Job $BackupJob

Comment: @user3770612 The default positional parameter of the cmdlet Start-Job is -Scriptblock. So, to specify a script file instead, add the -Filepath , like in my edited solution above.